# How to remove input disabled on click in angular 8

Tags: angular

I want to remove the input element disabled on click function in angular 8. I am having one form where there are different fields on click of span I want to remove the all input disabled class.

Comment: please provide and minimal example (a stackblitz link would be welcome too)

Comment: You should also clarify exactly what you want to remove, the disabled attribute or the input elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a disabled property to your inputs:

```
<input [disabled]="inputsDisabled"/>
<span (click)="enableInputs()">Enable</span>
```

And then set that property to `false` in your component:

```
enableInputs() {
  this.inputsDisabled = false;
}
```

If you need to toggle between disabled and enabled you can have this:

```
toggleInputsDisabled() {
  this.inputsDisabled = !this.inputsDisabled;
}
```

A downside of this is that you should add `[disabled]="inputsDisabled"` to every input field. Wrapping the inputs in a `<fieldset>` as so will make it easier to handle:

```
<fieldset [disabled]="inputsDisabled">
  <input/>
</fieldset>
```

Here's a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aczmug